# Float value manipulation in android

Tags: android

I want to separate float value from decimal point.

```
for ex:
Float f = 3.5
```

than i want

```
int value1 = 3
int value2 = 5
and if f = 4.0 than,
int value1 = 4
int value2 = 0
```

But please i could not do this with string manipulations. like Split

Thanks

Comment: What do you want value2 to be if there's more than one decimal place, e.g 3.54321?

Answer (score 1):

simply you can do is

```
int integer_part=(int)f;
float float_part=(f-integer_part);
string string_f=f+"";
int float_part=f*(string_f.length()-1)*10
```

Comment: you have 2 variables of different types with the same name.  Other than that, its an interesting solution

Comment: This will have the same problem as John's solution, i.e. if f > Integer.MAX_VALUE, you cannot cast it to a useful int.

Comment: you can use long, by the way do you have any problem in using string

Comment: if you can be specific to your problem then we could provide some solution. so plz edit and provide more details about your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the ones digit in value 1 and the tenths digit in value 2, you can do this:

```
value1 = (int)f;
value2 = ((int)(f * 10)) % 10;
```

Comment: @Matt, true, it would overflow.  Then he could do f = f - value1;  first for value2, that would work.

Comment: The first line would still not work, i.e. casting a float > Integer.MAX_VALUE to an integer would never work. So value1 would never be accurate.

Comment: In that case, there would be no solution then, except to cast it to a long.  I think that might be over-analyzing this issue a bit.